# Another way to create random dynamic url in javascript/stop wpengine from caching

Tags: javascript, variables, bigcommerce

I'm including a PHP file in a bigcommerce (formally interspire). The PHP file is from a wpengine site. Including the file looks like this: `%%Include.http://www.server.com/testing.php?store_id=4649b4c235fba82029176fa8a802c3%%`

And a howto is right here: http://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/209/How+do+I+Include+a+php,+html,+asp+or+any+other+type+of+file+in+an+Interspire+Knowledge+Manager+template+%3F

So, everything works fine, however, the file being included includes a clock that gets updated every minute, but the wpengine site is delivered via their own cdn, and so the clock is only updated every 20 minutes or so. If I change the url in any way, the cache resets.

I can reset the cache by saving the url as `%%Include.http://www.server.com/testing.php?store_id=4649b4c235fba82029176fa8a802c3&variable=123456789%%` and again as `%%Include.http://www.server.com/testing.php?store_id=4649b4c235fba82029176fa8a802c3&variable=987654321%%`

But if I try to make it dynamic by adding a js variable:

```
<script>
variable = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
document.write("%%Include.http://www.server.com/testing.php?store_id=4649b4c235fba82029176fa8a802c3&variable=" + variable + "%%");
</script>
```

It doesn't work, and I'm not really sure what's happening. The correct file and store_id are included, but the variable doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Any other ideas on how to include a dynamic variable or another way to keep the cdn from caching that page?

Comment: So you are including the file once but clock which is there in included file required to be updated every minute ?

Answer (score 0):

it depends what file you're using this in on BC but you may try appending the cache busting string that BC uses on some of their JS files, it just uses the date/timestamp I believe.

```
%%Include.http://www.server.com/testing.php?store_id=4649b4c235fba82029176fa8a802c3&variable=%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%%%
```

Haven't tried this one before, but I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You may try contacting WPE support and having them exclude the `store_id` argument from caching.